# F# non-trivial non-primary constructor

Tags: f#

I want to do some work in a non-primary constructor before calling the primary constructor, e.g. something like this:

```
type Foo(a:int,b:int) =
    let a = a
    let b = b
    new(s:string) =
        //...work here (intermediate let bindings)
        let _a = ...
        let _b = ...
        Foo(_a,_b)
```

If possible, how can I achieve this (now that I think about it, I'm not even sure if this can be done in C#, but the goal is similar to how you can call base constructors anywhere you like in an extending class constructor... but I don't want to do anything so sketch, just process my arguments a bit before deferring to the primary constructor -- or maybe I've been looking at computer screens too much today)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what you did but this works for me:

```
type Foo(a:int,b:int) =
    let a = a
    let b = b
    new (s:string) =
        printfn "some side effect"
        let _a = s.Length
        let _b = 1
        Foo(_a,_b)
```

In addition if you want to call base constructors in a derived type and pre or post insert code, here's the syntax FYI (beware of the braces placement):

```
type DFoo =
    inherit Foo

    new (a,b) =
        printfn "perform some validation here"
        let c = 0 // or bind stuff
        {
            inherit Foo(a,b)
        }
    new (s:string) =
        {
            inherit Foo(s)
        }
        then if s.Length = 0 then printfn "post ctor side effect"
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess my eyes really are tired! You know what I did? I started the non-primary constructor with `new Foo(s:string)`... there are so many variations on the type syntax I can never keep it straight.

Comment: Though it is nice that in this case the syntax turned out to be exactly as what I thought it should be (I tried all kinds of variations, searched around, almost got it right in my code, and then apparently got it right while typing out the question and thinking it was hypothetical)!

Comment: Most of the time F# try to minimize noise (compared to C++ or Java). `Foo` would be noise in `new Foo`, just `new` is sufficient signal.

Comment: Yeah, I appreciate that (though there are many deeper things to dislike about Java than syntax). But I think it's even more important for a language to have consistent and predictable signals (and avoid having multiple ways to do the same thing). For example, in this case, rather than `new` to signal a non-primary constructor, `Foo` might be better. Though maybe `new` is fine and the primary constructor syntax is off (I'm not sold on it's value for other reasons -- I'm tempted to always stick with `val` declarations to maintain control and keep things simple, but it's hard to avoid a feature).